# getters and setters for composit members C++

Tags: c++, oop, getter-setter, composition

I am learning C++ and I am having some trouble wrapping my head around getters and setters for objects that are members of other objects.

I have a DateOfBirth class with int month, int day, int year, and its appropriate getters and setters. I would like to have an instance of the DateOfBirth class as a private member of another class.

What would be the correct implementation for the getters/setters inside the container class?

Comment: @AnoopRana I don't think that addresses setting sub-members individually.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but it is not entirely clear that OP is having problem in setting sub-members individually. I mean they already have getters and setters for `DateOfBirth`. If there was some example code given by OP that would point to the statement where they're having issue it would've been clearer. I will reopen it ofcourse if/when the question becomes more clear.

Comment: I think I'll reopen now, and attempt an answer.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the code you are having a problem with

Comment: Before writing a setter - each time - also ask yourself what the use case is. How often do people change their date of birth?

Comment: Getters/setters is a bit of a *code smell*, and may be an opportunity to consider [Hollywood principle](https://deviq.com/principles/hollywood-principle).  (It's just a smell, it does **not** mean that they are automatically bad or always bad.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how expensive to copy `DateOfBirth` is. Since yours stores just a few `int`s, I'd write a getter/setter as usual:

```
const DateOfBirth &GetDate() const {return date;}
void SetDate(DateOfBirth new_date) const {date = new_date;}
```

But remember that there's no single correct implementation, what kind of setter to use depends on why you need it in the first place. If you don't need any custom logic on reading/writing the member (and don't anticipate needing it in the future), you can make the member public.

If the class is expensive to copy, you could make a setter return a non-const reference: `DateOfBirth &SetDate() {return date;}`, but this severely limits what logic you can add to the setter latter, at this point you might as well make the member public.

You could also implement setters for individual sub-members.

Or you could make the "setter" accept a function/lambda, which is given a non-const reference to the member as a parameter:

```
void SetDate(auto &&setter) {decltype(setter)(setter)(date);}
// Then:
x.SetDate([](DateOfBirth &date){date = ...;});
```

Answer (score 0):

One crude way(that matches your current given description) is as shown below:

```
class DateOfBirth 
{
  private:
    int month = 0, day = 0, year = 0;
  public:
    //getters 
    int getMonth() const 
    {
        return month;
    }
    int getDay() const 
    {
        return day ;
    }
    int getYear() const 
    {
        return year;
    }
    //setters
    void setMonth(int pmonth) 
    {
        month = pmonth;
    }
    void setDay(int pday)
    {
        day = pday ;
    }
    void setYear(int pyear)
    {
        year = pyear;
    }
};
class AnotherClas 
{
  DateOfBirth d; 
  public:
    //getter 
    DateOfBirth getDateOfBirth() const 
    {
        return d;
    }
    //setter 
    void setDateOfBirth(int pmonth, int pday, int pyear)
    {
        d.setMonth(pmonth); //set month 
        d.setDay(pday);     //set day 
        d.setYear(pyear);   //set year 
    }
};
int main()
{
    //create instance of another class 
    AnotherClas a; 
    a.setDateOfBirth(10, 2, 3);
    
    //lets confirm by printing 
    std::cout << a.getDateOfBirth().getMonth() << "-" << a.getDateOfBirth().getDay() << "-" << a.getDateOfBirth().getYear() <<std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/_FiHfA5Nh)

The output of the above program is:

```
10-2-3
```

Comment: What's the use case for this? Lots of code that does nothing.  Could just as well be `struct DateOfBirth {int year, month, day};` and then `DateOfBirth WhenEver {2024, 13, 42};`

Comment: @BoP I completely agree. But since the question doesn't itself has much clarity and quality, there's no point in arguing what exactly OP wants. I just presented one option that i think OP is describing.

Comment: The only point of having setters is when they do some input validation. Like check that 1 <= month <= 12, which it should do here. Without that just make the whole thing public. Which is what I would do with DateOfBirth. It makes sense to validate day/month/year inside DateOfBirth but once you have a validated DateOfBirth a setter makes no sense.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow There is no validation done in my code. I was thinking of adding validation but then i don't want to provide a complete homework solution to the question. Just enough to give some hints. I have seen before many times that when i(or someone else) provide complete solution. But i don't do that anymore. Just little hints depending on my understanding of the question.

Comment: @AnoopRana Understandable. But you can still remove the getter/setter in AnotherClass and use `a.dateOfBirth = DateOfBirth(10, 2, 3);`.